# I get error when I want to insert data to classes of model in django?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I learning django and I'm reading "https://docs.djangoproject.com" and try to do their example for myself.

My project name is "student" and  wrote two class in student's models,mysite/student/models:

```
from django.db import models

class student(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(max_length=3,primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id


class course_item(models.Model):
    course_id=models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    course_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    score=models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    std_id=models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    std_id = models.ForeignKey(student)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %d' % (self.course_name, self.student)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('course_id', 'std_id')
```

and this is my mysite/student/admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from student.models import *
admin.site.register(student)
admin.site.register(course_item)
```

When I want to add student and new course_item from "localhost:8000/admin/" I get this error for add student:

*TypeError at /admin/student/student/add/
'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'*

and get this error when I want add course_item:

*OperationalError at /admin/student/course_item/add/
(1054, "Unknown column 'student_course_item.std_id_id' in 'where clause'")*

I'm be happy if someone help me and I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Did you run: "python manage.py syncdb" to create the database?

Comment: yes i run it then run "python manage.py runserver",Is my classes have somthing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `std_id` for the class attribute, by default django will create a column with `property_id` in the database for ForeignKey fields.

Then, why have you 2 properties `std_id` ?

And in your exemple you do :

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %d' % (self.course_name, self.student)
```

but you don't have any student property in your model class, only a std_id.

try to change it by :

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    student = models.ForeignKey(student)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %d' % (self.course_name, self.student_id)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('course_id', 'student')
```

**EDIT**

And just for information, you don't need to manualy set the id property for your models, if you only want basic primary key identifier, django will create it for you, and you can access it by using modelInstance.pk or modelInstance.id

Comment: did you update your database ? be careful, if you use django < 1.7, the `python manage.py syncdb` don't update your fields in an existing table, you have to erase it or use [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for migrations